# Pandas Dataframe show rows with criteria desired

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working with my quantitative codes via python. I have been working with dataframe lately alot, and until yesterday, one freaking glitch hit me pretty hard, and I am pretty lost how to get my desired results:

this is the DOM:

```
   ts_code    end_date   fcff          roe_yearly  roa_dp  roic_yearly  roe_yoy   q_op_qoq 
0   603000.SH  20191231  1.041476e+08  10.8941     7.6454  12.6005       47.5085   356.2437
1   603000.SH  20190930 -1.431920e+08   4.2044     2.2306   4.8479       31.2632   -25.7032
2   603000.SH  20190630 -2.267375e+08   2.9238     1.0385   3.5750      276.4166   449.9221
3   603000.SH  20190331 -3.097644e+08  -3.1372    -0.5800  -3.7248       62.9496  -116.0415
4   603000.SH  20181231  1.775266e+08   7.4066     5.4977   8.3623      122.7574    71.7184
5   603000.SH  20180930  3.023451e+07   3.2345     1.8423   3.8565      307.8660    98.3655
6   603000.SH  20180630 -1.042179e+08  -1.6766    -0.6451  -1.1682       19.8322   186.0172
7   603000.SH  20180331 -2.138164e+08  -8.4060    -1.6109  -8.4708      -27.0477  -167.3619
8   603000.SH  20171231  3.593505e+08   3.2401     2.4328   3.4555      -17.1973    76.1037
9   603000.SH  20170930 -2.170032e+07   0.7884     0.4471   1.0209      -78.5932    49.9168
10  603000.SH  20170630  2.299095e+07  -2.0970    -0.7922  -1.9708     -188.7621   156.7807
11  603000.SH  20170331 -6.089507e+07  -6.6504    -1.2439  -7.7056     -217.9714  -485.1622
12  603000.SH  20161231 -8.746122e+08   3.9054     2.9030   6.4299      -61.9080   -69.2861
13  603000.SH  20160930 -8.630607e+08   3.7055     2.1016   6.8464      -51.4469  2306.0770
14  603000.SH  20160630 -2.855617e+08   2.3550     0.8761   7.2218      -49.3369  -101.6762
15  603000.SH  20160331 -3.922060e+08   5.7132     1.0855  14.7152      103.8043    -2.5653
16  603000.SH  20151231 -1.632709e+08  10.4885     7.7055  12.7376      -21.8468    14.4998
```

What I wanna filtered out is the annual report, which only shows `df['end_date']` matching rows with 1231 date ending. Can anyone give me a direction with to solve this? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea is convert values to strings and select values by indexing - values after first 4 numbers, compare by `1234` string and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['end_date'].astype(str).str[4:].eq('1231')]
print (df1)
      ts_code  end_date         fcff  roe_yearly  roa_dp  roic_yearly  \
0   603000.SH  20191231  104147600.0     10.8941  7.6454      12.6005   
4   603000.SH  20181231  177526600.0      7.4066  5.4977       8.3623   
8   603000.SH  20171231  359350500.0      3.2401  2.4328       3.4555   
12  603000.SH  20161231 -874612200.0      3.9054  2.9030       6.4299   
16  603000.SH  20151231 -163270900.0     10.4885  7.7055      12.7376   

     roe_yoy  q_op_qoq  
0    47.5085  356.2437  
4   122.7574   71.7184  
8   -17.1973   76.1037  
12  -61.9080  -69.2861  
16  -21.8468   14.4998
```

Solution wiorking with datetimes - first converting and then get months with days by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df1 = df[pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%m%d').eq('1231')]
```

Comment: thanks alot chief! one question, what does ```str[4:]``` stands for?

Comment: nevermind chief, i got what you mean by ```str[4:]```, it is matching the 5th to the end strings with exact 1231 expression.

Answer (score 2):

this can be done with string operations:

```py
df[df.end_date.astype(str).str.endswith("1231")]
```

result

```
      ts_code  end_date         fcff  roe_yearly  roa_dp  roic_yearly   roe_yoy  q_op_qoq
0   603000.SH  20191231  104147600.0     10.8941  7.6454      12.6005   47.5085  356.2437
4   603000.SH  20181231  177526600.0      7.4066  5.4977       8.3623  122.7574   71.7184
8   603000.SH  20171231  359350500.0      3.2401  2.4328       3.4555  -17.1973   76.1037
12  603000.SH  20161231 -874612200.0      3.9054  2.9030       6.4299  -61.9080  -69.2861
16  603000.SH  20151231 -163270900.0     10.4885  7.7055      12.7376  -21.8468   14.4998
```